# Laptop cpu fan replacement would this fan work?

Tags: laptop

In my [Dell Inspiron 15R SE](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-GENUINE-DELL-INSPIRON-15R-5520-7520-SE-CPU-FAN-SUNON-MAGLEV-D0D6C-0D0D6C-/171345170329?hash=item27e4f7cf99:g:ehoAAOxyzpdTiKB3) I have the original fan. The CFM of this fan is 9.3.

Can I replace that fan with [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-Inspiron-15R-5520-5720-7520-3760-SE-CPU-Fan-0D0D6C-D0D6C-XRF-DFS531205HCOT-/121997676660?hash=item1c67a0d074:g:yrUAAOSwR5dXRaH4)? The CFM on this fan is much higher 65. Will there be any performance issues and noise? Is it better to use the fan of the same brand?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

This is because the mount points for the screws are different:

[image]

It's unclear exactly why you want a higher airflow in your machine, however I suspect you want to cool the machine down quicker/more efficiently, in order to fix temperature issues. Even if a higher CFM fan did exist for your model, it is unlikely that it would be supported in your model's revision as higher CFM fans will use more power (that the specific revision of the model might not be able to provide).

Therefore to (partially) fix your temperature issues a [laptop cooling pad](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.XLaptop+Cooling+Pad.TRS0&_nkw=Laptop+Cooling+Pad&_sacat=0) may be better suited for your situation, as:

- It has its own fans built-in that attach to a USB port of your machine;
- They are relatively inexpensive;
- It may last longer than the life of your current machine (you may be able to use it for your next laptop)

Comment: There was a minor change in the mount points between dell inspiron 15r 7250 versions but the fan is the same Sunon Maglev. The mount points in my version is the same as which is given in the first pic. I want to change the fan because its making a bit of grinding noise. So which fan should i get should the replacement fan have the CFM.

Comment: @jaseon Doesn't matter; that's the model of the *fan*, not the part. The fan is still likely to spin slower for the reason I outlined, so it's best if you stick to the original part.